# Is it possible to use OAuth/Google AuthSub with just JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oauth, authsub

It seems very hard or downright impossible to take advantage of them purely in JavaScript, without a server side script (like one in PHP) helping (like masking the secret key.) However, I can only use JavaScript on this project. Is it still possible to use AuthSub or OAuth?

Comment: Did oauth not have a javascript sample in their code page? Its painful to understand and starts up a annoying browser to perform the Dance, but last time I checked it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use OAuth without doing crypto in browser, but you can use AuthSub. In fact google have a client library that makes it really easy :-

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/js-authsub.html